# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getConfigs')"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, react-redux

When I try to signup a new user using `email` and `password`. This is the error message I get from my redux-store: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getConfigs')"`. And  the request is being rejected.

This is the code where the error is coming from:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import qs from 'qs';

const defaultConfig = {
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
  paramsSerializer: (params) => qs.stringify(params, { arrayFormat: 'repeat' }),
};

export default class ApiService {
  static baseUrl = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}`;

  static getConfigs = (additionalConfig = {}) => {
    console.log('hello')
    const config = {
      ...defaultConfig,
      ...additionalConfig,
    };

    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    console.log('user', user)

    if (user && user.accessToken !== null) {
      config.headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${user.accessToken}` };
    }
   
    return config;
  };

  static get = async (url, params) => axios.get(url, this.getConfigs({ params }));

  static post = async (url, data) => axios.post(url, data, this.getConfigs());

  static put = async (url, data) => axios.put(url, data, this.getConfigs());

  static patch = async (url, data) => axios.patch(url, data, this.getConfigs());

  static delete = async (url) => axios.delete(url, this.getConfigs());

  static download = async (url) => axios.get(url, this.getConfigs());

  static upload = async (url, data) => {
    const config = this.getConfigs();
    config.headers['content-type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
    return axios.post(url, data, config);
  };
}
```

userService codebase:

```
import ApiService from './ApiService';

export default class UserService {
  static getUsers = async (filters) => ApiService.get('/users', filters);

  static getUser = async (userId) => ApiService.get(`/users/${userId}`);

  static getUserRoles = async (userId) => ApiService.get(`/users/${userId}/roles`);

  static createUser = async (user) => ApiService.post('/users', user);

  /**
   * Update the account level roles for a user
   *
   * @param {string} userId
   * @param {object{}} data
   * @returns
   */
  static updateAccountPassword = async (userId, data) => ApiService.patch(`/users/${userId}/update-password`, data);

  static updateAccountUser = async (userId, data) => ApiService.patch(`/users/${userId}`, data);
}
```

My usercreate actions and reducer

```
export const userCreate = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/userCreate',
  async ({ email, password }) => {
    console.log(email, password)
    const response = await UserService.createUser({ email, password });
    console.log('response', response);
    const data = await response.json();
    if (response.status >= 400 && response.status < 600) {
      throw new Error(data.failure);
    }
    console.log('data', data);
    return data;
  },
);

export const authServiceSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: {
    loading: false,
    error: null,
    data: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    logout: () => ({
      loading: false,
      error: null,
      data: null,
    }),
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [userCreate.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [userCreate.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      toast.error(action.error.message);
      state.error = action.error.message;
    },
    [userCreate.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.data = action.payload;
    },
    [userAuth.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [userAuth.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      toast.error(action.error.message);
      state.error = action.error.message;
    },
    [userAuth.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.data = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { logout } = authServiceSlice.actions;

export default authServiceSlice.reducer;
```

.env file content.

```
REACT_APP_API_URL = http://localhost:3000
```

I didn't write the `APIService` class code myself, where the issue is coming from. And I still can't figure out where the issue is. Any help pls?

Comment: All of your methods are `static`, but you are referring to `this`.  What do you think `this` refers to in that context?  To debug, If you add a breakpoint, what is `this` when the call is made?  `this` is likely `undefined`, which mean you can't refer to a property/method such as `getConfigs`.  Your second code excerpt doesn't even refer to the first.

Comment: @DaveMeehan I don't understand what you mean by referring to `this`. maybe you can elaborate more. Just as I earlier highlighted. I didn't write the code inside the `APIService` class. I was giving the code to use.

Comment: I have edited the codebase. I'm sure it will make more sense now.

Comment: e.g. `static get = async (url, params) => axios.get(url, this.getConfigs({ params })` <-- here you are referring to `this.getConfigs`.  You are in an arrow function assigned as a static property of `ApiService`.  What do you think `this` refers too at this point of execution?  Have you looked with a debugger?

Comment: You may not have written the `ApiService`, but it has an intended mode of use presumably?  Documentation?  If you have written `UserService`, are you using `ApiService` as intended?

Comment: Rewriting the `post` static property from using `arrow function` : `static post = async (url, data) => axios.put(url, data, this.getConfigs());` to the `standard function` :
`static post = async function(url, data) { 
    return axios.post(url, data, this.getConfigs())
  };` solved my issue.  This [link](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-use-javascript-arrow-functions-and-this-keyword/) was very helpful. Thanks @DaveMeehan for pointing me in the right direction.